# Increase drawing performance on an iPhone 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, calayer, drawrect

My first question on StackOverflow. So feeling kind of shy ...

I've been working and tweaking on an curstom control for some weeks now. It uses ±6 subclassed CALayers for some fancy animations to give the best possible user-feedback. Additionally there are 2 animated UIViews adding up to some heavy animation and redrawing during user interaction.

I managed to get the responsiveness and performance on an iPhone 5S up to +50fps. But on a iPhone 4, it really makes me cry: 8 ~ 15fps. I tried to figure out what causes this awfull performance, but till now I found nothing other than the fact I might be wanting to much from Core Animation.

Using *layer.drawsAsynchronously = YES;* on all CALayers increased the responsiveness by A LOT. And I also took out all unnecessary animations (including implicit animations). But it still isn't enough. The performance on an iPhone 4 is still not the way I want it.

I notice a lot of improvement when I switch to *layer.opaque = YES;* But due to the design of my interface, this really isn't an option.

Is there anyting you guys can suggest to look into? Are there any other "magic" properties, like *.drawsAsynchronously* I might want to try or look into?

Are there any resources you can suggest on how to debug/analyse the performance?

Any help is appriciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you post some code showing what you are trying to do?

Comment: Unfortunately, It's not just a small snippet of code, but multiple CALayer subclasses & views. The biggest issue if probably the fact that (multiple) BezierPaths & Gradients are calculated based on gestures.

Comment: One thing I've noticed degrading performance a lot on iPhone4 is transparency. Using opaque colors for backgrounds helps a lot.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the same manecosta, but unfortunately the Design doesn't allow me to use an opaque background. (Thanks to the iOS7 style blurred backgrounds and semitransparent overlays.)

Answer (score 0):

The quickest answer will be don't use drawRect: because it's very expensive.
CALayers are the best way.

If you need to draw something complex is good to consider Core Graphics because it use GPU instead of CPU which is much more effective. You can draw image with Core Graphics and add it to the view.

Have a look on this [link](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/)
There is good explanation how UIView works and how to write most efficient code

Comment: All animation and "expensive" drawing is done using CALayer subclasses, so I guess I'm working in the right direction.

Comment: @MichMich check out this link. If you have done your drawing with CALayer maybe better way is put your heavy animation code to stack overflow so someone can optimise it if possible.